# Livestreaming webcam

Tags: javascript, streaming

If I want to have the user livestream content from his own webcam is it possible to do it all on my server without installing any software on the user's end(OBS, flashplayer etc)?

Comment: yes it is possible using modern browsers

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using `navigator.getUserMedia` on modern browsers.

Check : [Accessing your webcam in html 5](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/accessing_your_webcam_in_html5.htm)